# How to draw simple coordinate axes in OpenGL 3

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have been trying to make a relatively simple simulator using OpenGL (specifically with the LWJGL library but I'm thinking that won't affect this). I'm using OpenGL 3 and [have been following this tutorial](https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/chapter14/chapter14.html).

I am using VBOs and VAOs to render meshes without issue, but now I want to render some coordinate axes in the world for orientation and reference, and all of the information I can find online is around the use of `glBegin` which is not available in OpenGL 3, so I am confused. The existing shaders I am using for my 3D world accept 3D position vectors, but in order to draw "infinite" axes, I need to use the homogeneous coordinate. Would it be more common practice to pass the full 4D vector to the shader instead? Setting the 4th component to 1 in most cases?

Do I really need to go the lengths of creating a VBO and whatnot just to draw 3 straight lines on the screen?

Comment: If you're already using vertex buffers, then what is the problem of throwing the content of the `glBegin` into one?

Comment: Yes you really do. OpenGL doesn't make any assumptions about what you want to draw.